A universal "back" that works across all apps and tabs (MacOS or Windows)
It would be so useful to just have a universal "back" command that took you back to the previous window arrangment / tab you were on last - etc - something that just keeps track of the state of the UI over your full Operating system and just lets you hop back to where you were before.  Sort of like a Ctrl-Z but for the state of your UI.  It would track, and be able to reverse, UI state changes like

Going to a new URL in your current tab
Switching tabs within a browser/application
Switching applications
Opening/closing applications

Does any app or tool like this exist?  It seems so basic and yet I have never seen anything like this in a lifetime of working with computers.

That's very far from "basic"... E.g. reversing closing an application could have lots of issues  if you wanted to bring it to the same state, it'd be nearly impossible to code. Only reopening it in its starting state would be easy. Then there's a lot of discussion to be done of what actually should be registered as an action in the app. Because it won't know it magically, you need to feed the undo functionality the info as to what exactly is "UI state change", for each of them and what to revert to. So changing URL in a browser needs to be caught and registered, with previous URL. Etc.

Well - basic from the user experience perspective - apparently not from a technical perspective!  "Take me back to where I was before" is a pretty common requirement.  It's surprising to still see no real support for it on any major OS.
